# Can PlaceAutocompleteFragment (overlay mode) be called from inside the Fragment class

Tags: java, android-fragments, autocomplete, widget

I'm working on my project to create an activity(extends AppCompatActivity) with navigation drawer for switching between multiple Fragments and one of them is a MapFragment(extends Fragment) with a MapView implementation. **I would like to call the AutoComplete Widget, provided by Google, inside MapFragment class.**

Here is my code inside class MapFragment

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                    + place.getId() + "\n"
                    + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                    + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                    + place.getAttributions();
            Log.i("OnPlaceSelected", placeDetailsStr);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(), 15));

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("OnPlaceSelected", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

syntax error was at

`PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);`

said that

> Inconvertible type; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment'

But when I put this set of code inside MainActivity, it works just fine. **So I'm wondering if there's any way to call AutoComplete Widget inside Fragment it's just can't.**

Any Answer will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use getActivity()

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use something like this if you're trying to find the fragment from within a fragment:

```
placeAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaces);
```

You might run into issues with **onPlaceSelected** not being called, this is because your owning activity has to forward the result into the fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mapFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and **mapFragment** has to forward the result into the places fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    placeAutocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Even with this, I've had issues with **onPlacesSelected** not being called. Its usually best to just not nest the map and places fragments, but just have them separate in the owning activity.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching around on the interwebz too and couldn't find a solution, until I realised I had the same exact problem with the MapFragment, so I applied that technique and it worked!

## Fragment:

```
private SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     ...

    autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    if(autocompleteFragment==null){
        autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.instantiate(context, "com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment");
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {

            }
        });

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.autocomplete_fragment, autocompleteFragment).commit();
    }

     ...
```

Note: I am using the support fragment (android.support.v4.app.Fragment), that's why I use SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment

## XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment` instead of `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`, it's replaced when using Fragment supportv4

```
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment 
    = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same question, and thanks to @Kalpesh idea, it works fine, and no problem of eventListenner, here's my code if it can help someone.

I have a tablayout with a viewpager and 3 fragment we can swipe right or left.

> googlePLacesLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorFragment_bg">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/largeTexxt"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> MyFragmentClass.java

```
package com.raccoon.trash.aregood.TabFragments;
public class MyFragmentClass extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.googlePLacesLayout, container, false);

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setHint("Let's find some restaurants");

    final TextView textView = (TextView) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.largeTexxt);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            textView.setText("Place: " + place.getName()+ place.getId()+
                    place.getAddress()+ place.getPhoneNumber()+ place.getWebsiteUri());
            System.out.println("Place: " + place.getName()+ place.getId()+
                    place.getAddress()+ place.getPhoneNumber()+ place.getWebsiteUri());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

return mRelativeLayout;
}
```

}